# Could not get next value from sequence in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, sequence, rowcount

I am trying to get next value from sequence using the command in dbeaver, but getting this error

```
SQL Error [11739] [S0001]: NEXT VALUE FOR function cannot be used if ROWCOUNT option has been set, or the query contains TOP or OFFSET.
```

This is how i am fetching the sequence

```
SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR SERVICEVRSNS.CountBy1
```

What is wrong which i am doing here. In the above query i have not used TOP or Offset command.
How to resolve this issue.

This is how i created my sequence

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SERVICEVRSNS.CountBy1  
    START WITH 1  
    INCREMENT BY 1 ;
```

Comment: Seems like you have a ROWCOUNT in effect from a previous query. Try `SET ROWCOUNT 0; SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR SERVICEVRSNS.CountBy1;` instead.

Comment: What @AlwaysLearning said: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ea2a5cd5165f596b46eca58b4fc8d4d9

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, may be you can put this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

use as @AlwaysLearning said set ROWCONUT 0; and then your query